# Single api endpoint to post to different tables depending on a value in body

Tags: rest, clean-architecture

im new to clean architecture and I’d like to create a single api endpoint `/configuration` that saves values to different tables in my database. This is dependent on the value `config_name` passed in the body.

Tables:

- Table A
- Table B

Example request body:

```
{ 
 config_name: “tableA”,
 data: [{ id: “ABC-1”, name: “Echo”, country: “United States”, …}]
}
```

```
{
 config_name: “tableB”,
 data: [{ id: “XYZ”, name: “United States”, continent: “North America”, currency: “dollars”}]
}
```

Meaning, once POST `/configuration`,
the following logic is executed:

```
if config_name===“tableA” then save to tableA, 
else if config_name===“tableB” then save to table B.
```

So the ask here, Is this approach allowed in clean architecture? If so, whats the best way to tackle this to avoid dependencies between classes.
I’m implementing this in TS/Inversify

So far, I have set up the following in my code.

- ConfigController
- ConfigCommand
- ConfigRepository

Im injecting each instances via constructor (i.e: ConfigCommand in ConfigController).

Answer (score 0):

I would look at this as if the config endpoint was a reverse proxy that forwards the request to the right use case based on a parameter. So, instead of having a `ConfigCommand`, I'd have a `ConfigTableACommand`, `ConfigTableBCommand`, etc. (hopefully with better names than that!) so the Config endpoint would deserialize the parameters based on `config_name` and send the right command. Then each use case (for each "table") can implement whatever validations and logic you might need to do in each case and use an interface to store the specific data on each case (`ITableARepository`, `ITableBRepository`, etc).

The advantage of this approach is that your Core will be independent of the fact that all requests come from a single endpoint, which is something that could change in the future and it should not have any impact on the core part, and the repository interfaces can be very concrete for each data structure (as in the fields to store, not the actual DB data structure).

Comment: thanks a lot for this advice. I’ll definitely take this into account.